# Google Analytics date range picker / dashboard - How to use date picker present in Google Analytics for a custom web app?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I have been looking into Google Analytics as a solution for building a custom dashboard. Looking at a demo (https://datastudio.google.com/u/0/#/org//reporting/0B_U5RNpwhcE6TmpwV2hBOGdKYWM/page/qlD/preview) I want to replicate the calendar range picker.

First, I want to understand that if this is possible, does Google allow for usage in external apps?

Second, if anyone has used this control, how can I go about incorporating the calendar range picker in an app I am developing?

Answer (score 0):

I've recently published DatePicker which supports **two date ranges in one date picker** (similar to the one in Google Analytics):

- https://github.com/petrkotek/DatePicker

As you can see on github, it's a fork of https://github.com/foxrunsoftware/DatePicker.

Feel free to add issue on github if you come across any bug or contact me directly.

## Additional features (+screenshots)

**Two date ranges in one datepicker:**

[image]

**DateRangesWidget (this feature is still more experimental - I'm currently working on that)**

[image]